# Set the value of xml element to reference value of another xml element

Tags: xml

I am writing a configuration file in xml and I want to use the value of one xml element in another xml element.
It should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <PORT>8080</PORT>
        <URL>http://url:8080</URL>
    </configuration>
```

Instead of `8080` inside the `<URL>` tag, I would like to take the value of `<PORT>`.
Is there any way to do this in xml?

Comment: It depends on the application that processes the XML.

Comment: The xml will be processed by Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you're requesting, but you could use an entity reference...

```
<!DOCTYPE configuration [
<!ENTITY port "8080">
]>
<configuration>
    <PORT>&port;</PORT>
    <URL>http://url:&port;</URL>
</configuration>
```